# Try to get convexity defects but getting an error

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror

currently i am working on a final project. And i am using opencv library and python language. Studying on opencv with python, to understand how to use it i am making small projects. In this i try to find contours, hull and convexity defects on a hand photo. But when i run my code, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 21, in <module>
    defects = cv.convexityDefects(cnt, hull)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'convexhull'
```

I am studying on some documents of opencv and took line of codes from there. I found contours and hull but when it comes to convexitydefects every time i get an error. I already tried other people codes on internet and implement it into mine, gives me same error. I am new at python programming and can not fix this. Can anyone help me?
Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.resize(cv.imread("hand.jpg"), (350, 700))

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 230, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnt = contours[0]

hull = []

for i in range(len(contours)):
    hull.append(cv.convexHull(contours[i], False))
    cv.drawContours(img, hull, i, (0, 0, 255), 2, 8)

if len(hull) > 0:
    defects = cv.convexityDefects(cnt, hull)
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]
        start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
        end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
        far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
        cv.circle(img, far, 5, [0, 0, 255], -1)

cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv.imshow('Image', img)
cv.imshow('Thresh', thresh)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `cv.convexityDefects` expects input of type `Ptr<cv::UMat>`. But you are clearly passing a list(`hull`).

I believe instead of checking `if len(hull) > 0:` you probably need to loop through each element in hull.

Check the code below for mentioned change.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.resize(cv.imread("hand.jpg"), (350, 700))

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 230, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(
    thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnt = contours[0]

hull = []

for i in range(len(contours)):
    hull.append(cv.convexHull(contours[i], False))
    cv.drawContours(img, hull, i, (0, 0, 255), 2, 8)

for each in hull:
    defects = cv.convexityDefects(cnt, each)
    if not defects:
        continue
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]
        start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
        end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
        far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
        cv.circle(img, far, 5, [0, 0, 255], -1)

cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv.imshow('Image', img)
cv.imshow('Thresh', thresh)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Well now it gives this error: ```defects = cv.convexityDefects(cnt, each)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-oduouqig\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:329: error: (-215:Assertion failed) hpoints > 0 in function 'cv::convexityDefects'
'```. But i understand what you say and its really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Can you share may be the image you are getting error with? Looks like we might need to add some additional validation for to make it work. I tried with a random hand image from internet and it looked like working.

Comment: The image i used is : https://images.app.goo.gl/9yfrarSBG3sEQxTk9. I hope this is the right link.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening. Not an expert in image processing. But may be to do with the fact the program is only finding 1 contour for the image you provided. Anyway check this thread out https://answers.opencv.org/question/71424/convexitydefect-for-point-or-line/.

Comment: Also try with https://images.app.goo.gl/FMYUMtqs5s3vTR6P7 image and check if it is working as expected. I think you might need some additional checks to stop the program based on contour length or something based on your requirement.

Comment: I already checked the link you sent. But yeah you do have a point. I just don't know how to do it. I continue to search. And i tried the image you sent. It does'nt give any error. But result is not satisfying. Thresh values are not correct and the code is not enough to make it smoother. https://answers.opencv.org/question/228694/convexitydefects-errors/ in this page saying for finding defects need to indices of contour points that makes the hull. Maybe this is solution but i can't find indices. Thanks again.